# In SoapUi how create a Soap Request via groovy script?

Tags: soap, groovy, request, soapui

When I run that code via command-line the last step is not created. How can I create a Soap request?

```
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.*  
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.WsdlInterfaceFactory
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.registry.WsdlTestRequestStepFactory
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.registry.GroovyScriptStepFactory

String projectName = "Teste";
String projectPath = "C:/XX/";
String fullProjectPath = "$projectPath$projectName" + ".xml";
String pathToWSDL = "MY_WSDL?wsdl";

def currentProject = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project;

WsdlProject project = new WsdlProject();
project.setName(projectName);

WsdlInterface iface = WsdlInterfaceFactory.importWsdl(project,pathToWSDL, true)[0]
context.testCase.testSuite.project.save("");

project.addNewTestSuite('Teste');
project.getTestSuiteByName('Teste').addNewTestCase('Teste');


project.getTestSuiteByName('Teste').getTestCaseByName('Teste').addTestStep(GroovyScriptStepFactory.GROOVY_TYPE, "GroovyScript")
project.getTestSuiteByName('Teste').getTestCaseByName('Teste').addTestStep(WsdlTestRequestStepFactory.REQUEST_TYPE, "SOAP")
```

If i run in command-line i get this:
[Command-line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ToKWd.png)

If i run via SoapUi i get 2 pop ups :
[Pop Up1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Asnm1.png)
[Pop Up2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M58v9.png)
After i click OK on both i get what i want:
[SOAPUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9XBUr.png)

Comment: Is there any error output, or does silently fail to do the final step

Comment: I added more information on the post.

Comment: Purely out of curiosity, what benefit do you get from creating test cases and steps like this on the fly?

Comment: The objective is create a template for automate some tests, the only step that i missing is that one.

Comment: If someone knows how to do ok in the pop ups. It is another option. I gess.

Comment: Humour me.  Do you run everything form the command line?  Do you not use the GUI?